# How can I prevent HTTPS on another domain from wrongly showing on my HTTP-only domain?

Tags: https, google-index, http

So, I have a blog at `domain.com`. This blog is HTTP-only because I would gain almost nothing from adding SSL support. I have a web service now that I want to enable SSL support on that runs on the same server and IP address as my blog. I got it all working pretty easily, but not if I go to `https://domain.com` I will see a huge warning about an SSL certificate error and then if I click "ok" through the warning, I'll see the web service with SSL support, not my blog.

My biggest fear with this scheme is Google indexing an HTTPS version of it and penalizing my blog because the content between the two doesn't match.

How can I somehow for my blog's domain to either not serve anything on HTTPS, or to redirect back to my HTTP blog, or to serve my blog, but with an invalid SSL certificate?

What can I do, preferably without buying another dedicated IP for my website?

Answer (score 1):

The easier idea would be to install SSL on a subdomain ex. `secure.mysite.com` and place your encrypted pages there or vise a versa

Answer (score 0):

I recently enabled SSL for all of my sites.  They all run on the same server with a single ip address.  You can get this to work if you can get multi-domain wildcard certificate.  This type of certificate will allow you to use virtual hosts under SSL.  Since there is only one certificate for multiple domains, it is used by apache before the `host` header is sent, then once the `host` header is sent, apache uses the virtual host directives to serve the correct site.

Wildcard certificates can be expensive, but I found an affordable way of implementing this.  I got the certificate through https://www.startssl.com/.  You have to pay a $60 fee to prove your identity to them (along with providing photo id and a second form of id).  Then you have to verify your domains (free), and you can issue as many certificates as you want that cover any or all of them.